# Issue creating select in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I've got this and it's not working (SQL syntax error):

```
SELECT database_percent, national_percent, (database_percent/national_percent) AS calculated_index INT(3) FROM full_data_complete
```

If I take out the `INT(3)` part, it runs fine.

I'm looking to create a select that comes in `INT(3)` as the format. What do I need to do for this?

Comment: If you're trying to cast, take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: Not sure how this relates to my issue

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "comes in INT(3) as the format"?
Can you give an example?

Comment: Generally, one does not specify a column type when selecting. However you can force MySQL to cast a value to a specific data type.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you can use one of the following:

```
SELECT database_percent, national_percent, format(database_percent/national_percent, 0) AS calculated_index FROM full_data_complete
```

or

```
SELECT database_percent, national_percent, cast(database_percent/national_percent as signed) AS calculated_index FROM full_data_complete
```

or

```
SELECT database_percent, national_percent, round(database_percent/national_percent, 0) AS calculated_index FROM full_data_complete
```

I hope this helps.